# display selected image in background before submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where you can add a banner picture.
I would like to display the selected picture in a background of a div before the form is submitted.

I found this code here that looks nice and work for me, however it display in in an  element I would like to modify it to bake it displayed in the  element as the background... as I know nothing about JS... how should I proceed?

```css
.banner{
  display: flex;
  align-items:flex-end;
  height:250px;
  background-size: 1112px 250px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: rgba(32, 117, 252, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="headertitle">Add a New System : 
      <input type="text" name="system" placeholder="System's name" 
             value="<?php if(isset($_POST["addsystem"]) and !empty($_POST["system"])){echo $_POST["system"];}?>">
    </div>
    <div class="headerline">Add a Banner <i>(1112px X 250px)</i> :
      <input type="file" name="banner" id="profile-img">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function readURL(input) {
      if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
          $('#profile-img-tag').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
      }
    }
    $("#profile-img").change(function(){
      readURL(this);
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set it as the CSS `background` of the element with the `url()` value and make sure that the element with the `id` of `profile-img-tag` is an element that can have a background, like a `div`.

```css
.banner{
  display: flex;
  align-items:flex-end;
  height:250px;
  background-size: cover;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: rgba(32, 117, 252, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="headertitle">Add a New System : 
      <input type="text" name="system" placeholder="System's name" 
             value="<?php if(isset($_POST["addsystem"]) and !empty($_POST["system"])){echo $_POST["system"];}?>">
    </div>
    <div class="headerline">Add a Banner <i>(1112px X 250px)</i> :
      <input type="file" name="banner" id="profile-img">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function readURL(input) {
      if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
          $('.banner').css('background', "url(" + e.target.result + ")" );
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
      }
    }
    $("#profile-img").change(function(){
      readURL(this);
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: I copy pasted this but doesn't work ... do I need to do something else as well? 

(I am 200% noob in JS)

Comment: @agone07 Try logging `e.target.result` to see what that actually is providing.

Comment: @agone07 See my updated answer. You also need to make sure the element that will have the background image is an element that can have a background image, like a `div`.

Comment: what should I write in the <div class="banner" > to make it work?

Comment: @agone07 You just need to add an element that can display a background image. A `div` will work. Then you need to reference that element instead of  `#profile-img-tag`.

Comment: Ok done for displaying it, however it doesn't take my css into account ... the image is not taking all the space ... see my answer below

Comment: @agone07 That CSS is mostly about the container and wouldn't affect the background, except change `background-size: 1112px 250px;` to `background-size:cover;`. Also, your "answer" isn't really the answer to your question. Please delete it and mark my answer as the answer.